# Android device behaves differently when plugged in USB vs not plugged in

Tags: android, multithreading, background, sleep

I am running tests on an HTC Magic (Dev phone 2). I have 3 background AsyncTasks. One downloads data from a server, one wakes the screen up once a minute and the last keeps the application alive for a given duration. The download thread asynctask seems to work correctly, and while it is downloading(~1hr) the other two seem to work as well. But once the downloads are done if the phone is unplugged the other two threads don't work properly(screen doesn't wake up and the keepAlive never ends). It almost seems like they stop altogether, then if I plug the phone into the computer they start up again... I am not sure what could be causing this, the screen wakeup should be preventing the device from going to sleep.

All my code can be found here: https://homepage.usask.ca/~mcb394/Receive.java or the two classes that seem to stop working after the download completes and when unplugged are below. Any thoughts would be awesome.

```
    /**
 * This class keeps the phone alive for the entire duration necessary to use all the data (think of a media player buffer)
 * @author michael bullock
 */
private class KeepRunning extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


        try {
            Thread.sleep(ALIVE_TIME_MS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            out.print(" KeepRunning Crashed!!!!!\n");
            out.flush();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        out.print(" KeepRunning Completed\n");
        out.flush();
        timeCompleted = true;
        return null;
    }
}


/**
 * This class powers the phone's screen up every WAKEUP_EVERY ms, stays awake for 1s
 * This is so the phone avoids going to sleep
 * @author michael bullock
 */
private class WakeUp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, getClass().getName());

        do{

            try {
                Thread.sleep(WAKEUP_EVERY); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           

            wl.acquire();
            Log.i("", "********** Acquired Wakelock **********");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("", "********** Releasing Wakelock **********");
            wl.release();

        }while(!timeCompleted || !transferCompleted);

        out.print(" WakeUp Completed\n");
        out.flush();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: I put some timestamped log statements in my code and here is what I found... the WakeUp class that is supposed to wakeup the screen every minute works until the download is finished. Once the network activity stops it starts waking up the screen every 10 minutes rather than 1 minute. I broke my other thread of KeepRunning into smaller sleeps and it showed a similar results. Very bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

The service or activity running this `AsyncTask` may be getting killed, which might be affected by being on battery power. Try using a service and using `Service.startForeground`.

Comment: I don't believe the activity is dying, I added some timestamped log statements to try and get a solid idea of what was going on and it appears to just be a 10x slowdown when unplugged.

Comment: I also just noticed that you are acquiring a wakelock for a few ms and then relinquishing it. Try getting the wakelock for the entire time you are downloading. You may also only need a CPU wakelock.

Comment: Yeah the wakelock is to keep the device from going to sleep and destroying my network connections. The reason I only acquire it briefly every minute was because it seems as if 802.11 PSM is turned off when the screen is on - and my tests rely on the PSM. I'll try running it with the CPU only wakelock on for the entire duration and see what happens. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: For an update - if I use the screen wakelock for the entire test, the test passes, but no PSM. If I use the CPU (Partial) wake lock for the entire time my network connections timeout and the app throws an exception.

Comment: Sort of. It works but not in the state I want it in. It works when the screen is on. I need to run it with the screen off so I can take advantage of the wifi radio going to sleep. When the screen is off rather than waking up every 1minute like it should it wakes up every 10 minutes.

Comment: It's odd that using `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` stops your code. A different approach you might try would be to use `AlarmManager`, as shown in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233764/android-how-to-download-data-in-the-background-at-specified-times/3233863#3233863

Comment: @Michael: From where exactly do you have the information that 802.11 PSM is turned off? I am interested in that.