# Android Background download data

Tags: android

I want to make a background running service (independent of an app) which would download weather data from server periodically every day. I already have code to download data from the server and store it in the database.

What I would like to know is, what is the best way to run the service periodically.

Answer (score 2):

You can Create a Android Intent Service :-

```
public class BackendService extends IntentService {
    public BackendService() {
        super("BackendService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Your Download code
    }
}
```

Then set a Alarm Receiver to set the interval in which service will be called.

```
public void backendscheduleAlarm() {
    // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackendAlarm.class);
    // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, BackendAlarm.REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Setup periodic alarm every 1 hour
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // first run of alarm is immediate
    int intervalMillis = 3000; //3600000; // 60 min
    AlarmManager backendalarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    backendalarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, intervalMillis, pIntent);
}
```

And Create a Broadcast Receiver class to call that service:

```
public class BackendAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;
// Triggered by the Alarm periodically (starts the service to run task)
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, BackendService.class);
    i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
    context.startService(i);
} }
```

Comment: thanks for the manual, may i ask when to call the backendscheduleAlarm? and this will "survive" even if device is rebooted?

Comment: Call it whenever you require, I use it when application starts. I have never tested that.

Comment: @Guilherme Bernal, 
When i destroy the app, the AlarmManager will still work?

Answer (score 0):

read about Android Services which are mainly made for such background work:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

all you need is to start the service on a certain time you set.